# Server 2012 active directory first login

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I'm beginner with Windows Server 2012 and Active Directory
I've got installed Active Directory remotely on my server and after the installation is finished and system restarted now I can't login into the server using my Administrator user.
How can I login into my server remotely as my Administrator user.
I've tried everything (Administrator, MyDomain/Administrator,....)
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using your password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your username will be DOMAIN\Administrator
Your password will be the same as the local admin password from pre-promotion.

I have heard of weird occurances where the administrator password is set to the "DSRM" password which you entered when promoting your domain controller - although I have never experienced this and am not even sure how thats possible?!

If you were using Remote Desktop Services and have not fully patched your server - AD DS and RDS cannot co-exist:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2799605
You will need to fully patch your DC for this to work.

If you have forgotten your admin password - its time to boot into Directory Services Restore Mode (DSRM) and change the password - you have (hopefully) made a note of your DSRM password which you were prompted for as part of the DC Propmotion.

Also, if this was the case, you may find that RDP is disabled and therefore, you will need console access to the server to enable it and also to disable the windows firewall (never a good idea to have it on a DC)

BHope this helps,